# How to show the active service workers in the firefox dev tools?

Tags: firefox, service-worker, firefox-developer-tools

In the Chrome Developer tools (pressing F12), I can see all service workers, accessing the *Application* tab, selecting *Service Workers menu*, checking *"Show All"*.

**How can I do it, in the Firefox ?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Type `about:debugging#workers` in your address bar, 
or in a more natural way:

`Menu -> Web Developer -> Service Workers`.

Comment: That menu item doesn't exist in Firefox Dev Edition 68, but `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox` works.

Comment: Only `about:debugging#workers` works in FireFox 68.0.2.

Comment: @IanDunn; same here, no `Menu -> Web Developer -> Service Workers`, can u tell me where is it in the current version, if u r using it? thanx

Comment: It moved to menu -> tools -> web developer -> application

Answer (score 3):

On `about:serviceworkers` (checked on Firefox 72) there is another interface from where you can also *unregister* or remove service workers.

Not sure why there are two different interfaces to deal with service workers in Firefox.

JUNE 2020 EDIT: I've noticed that on Firefox 76 from `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox` you can also now unregister service workers, functionality that previously wasn't available from this page. The funny thing is that this updated page is also on Firefox 72! The code for this page must be updated remotely without the need of updating Firefox. Didn't know that Mozilla integrated this functionality into the browser.

Comment: Ya, and they both suck compared to what Chrome offers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see them in the `serviceworker.txt` file in your profile.

If you have many of these service workers and want to disable them all, an easy way is to rename or move that file and restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

`about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`

visit that in your firefox browser